# Merge header columns in a matrix in bash but keeping columns that have value in same row separate

Tags: bash, matrix

I want to merge the headers of the matrix (FS is tab):

```
    12  12  12  13
bb  2   
cc  8   3               
aa          5
ee              6
```

like this:

```
        12     12     13
bb      2        
cc      8       3 
aa              5
ee                     6
```

I tried this

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t";maxcolno=1} {printf "%s",$1;if(NR==1){for(oldi=2;oldi<=NF;oldi++){if(!($oldi in newcolno)){printf "%s%s",OFS,$oldi;newcolno[$oldi]=++maxcolno;}old2new[oldi]=newcolno[$oldi];}}else{delete row;for(oldi=2;oldi<=NF;oldi++)row[old2new[oldi]]=row[old2new[oldi]]$oldi;for(newi=2;newi<=maxcolno;newi++)printf "%s%s",OFS,row[newi];}print""}' unmerge.txt > merge.txt
```

but it forms the following table which is not desired:

```
        12     13     
bb      2        
cc      83        
aa      5        
ee             6
```

Comment: so, merge the columns in the middle?  do the value at the top need to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- values are to be left-shifted within a row when there is an empty space (to the left) in a column of the same label; this means the `aa / 5` value should be shifted to the 1st `12` column (as opposed to the 2nd `12` column as in OP's expected output)

General design:

- populate a matrix with the input data
- as we process a data row we determine the left-most column in which to shift/place a value
- in the `END{}` block we remove empty columns and then print the remaining matrix

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }

NR==1 { matrix[NR][1]=$1
        for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
            matrix[NR][i]=$i
            lab2col[$i][++labcnt[$i]]=i                          # keep track of list of physical columns that a particular label is associated with
        }
        next
      }

      { matrix[NR][1]=$1
        delete labcnt
        for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)                                      # loop through input fields and ...
            if ($i) {                                            # if non-empty then shift to the left-most column with the same header/label
               matrix[NR][lab2col[matrix[1][i]][++labcnt[matrix[1][i]]]]=$i
               #                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ - label at top of current field
               #                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - number of times we have seen this label in this line
               #          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - physical column to map this nth occurrence (of this label) to
            }
      }

END   { # find/remove empty columns

        for (j=2;j<=NF;j++) {                                   # loop through list of data columns
            valcnt=0                                            # initialize non-empty counter
            for (i=2;i<=NR;i++)                                 # loop through data rows
                valcnt+= (matrix[i][j] ? 1 : 0)                 # keep count of non-empty matrix values
            if (valcnt==0)                                      # if all rows in this column are empty then ...
               delete matrix[1][j]                              # delete the column index from the header/1st row of the matrix
        }

        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"                    # make sure we process indices in ascending numerical order

        for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {                                   # loop through rows
            for (j in matrix[1]) {                              # loop through columns (that still exist in the 1st row of the matrix)
                printf "%s%s", (j==1 ? "" : OFS), matrix[i][j]  # print matrix entry
                pfx=OFS
            }
            print ""                                            # terminate current line of output
        }
      }
' unmerge.txt
```

**NOTE:** requires `GNU awk` for:

- multi-dimensional arrays (aka array of arrays)
- the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` feature

This generates:

```
        12      12      13
bb      2
cc      8       3
aa      5
ee                      6
```

---

Expanding the input a bit:

```
$ cat unmerge2.txt
        12      12      12      13      12      13
bb      2
cc      8                               3
aa                      5
ee                              6
ff                              17      87
gg                              100             -3
```

The `awk` script generates:

```
        12      12      13      13
bb      2
cc      8       3
aa      5
ee                      6
ff      87              17
gg                      100     -3
```